# Want to remove only key from index not values in php

Tags: php, json

I have array in php and convert that in json.Now
I have this code in json format

```
{
    "2": "12:40 to 13:0",
    "3": "13:0 to 13:20",
    "4": "13:20 to 13:40",
    "5": "13:40 to 14:0",
    "6": "14:0 to 14:20",
    "7": "14:20 to 14:40",
    "8": "14:40 to 15:0",
    "9": "15:0 to 15:20",
    "10": "15:20 to 15:40",
    "11": "15:40 to 16:0",
    "12": "16:0 to 16:20",
    "13": "16:20 to 16:40",
    "14": "16:40 to 17:0",
    "15": "17:0 to 17:20",
    "16": "17:20 to 17:40",
    "17": "17:40 to 18:0"
```

}
in json format 
but i want to remove indexes 2,3,4,5 form code and want data in

```
    {
       "12:40 to 13:0",
         "13:0 to 13:20",
        "13:20 to 13:40",
        "13:40 to 14:0",
         "14:0 to 14:20",
        "14:20 to 14:40",
        "14:40 to 15:0",
        "15:0 to 15:20",
         "15:20 to 15:40",
         "15:40 to 16:0",
         "16:0 to 16:20",
        "16:20 to 16:40",
         "16:40 to 17:0",
        "17:0 to 17:20",
         "17:20 to 17:40",
          "17:40 to 18:0"
}
```

any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove keys and keep just values using PHP's [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Just do `json_decode` and then use `array_values`.

By default, array indexes are numeric.

If you generate the array e.g. `$arr = array('PHP', 'JAVA')`, you will get

This is numeric array

`$arr = (0 => 'PHP', '1' => 'JAVA')`

Now, if we create a new associative array.

`$arr = ('scripting' => 'PHP', 'programming' => 'JAVA')`

So, array_values converts the array into numeric array from associative array.

Answer (score 3):

[array_values](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_values.asp).

An [authoritative](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) resource, too:

```
array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$json = '{
    "2": "12:40 to 13:0",
    "3": "13:0 to 13:20",
    "4": "13:20 to 13:40",
    "5": "13:40 to 14:0",
    "6": "14:0 to 14:20",
    "7": "14:20 to 14:40",
    "8": "14:40 to 15:0",
    "9": "15:0 to 15:20",
    "10": "15:20 to 15:40",
    "11": "15:40 to 16:0",
    "12": "16:0 to 16:20",
    "13": "16:20 to 16:40",
    "14": "16:40 to 17:0",
    "15": "17:0 to 17:20",
    "16": "17:20 to 17:40",
    "17": "17:40 to 18:0"
}';

$data = (array)json_decode($json); //your json data
$data_values = array_values($data);//if you want array
$newStr = "{".implode(',', $data_values)."}"; // if you want string
$newJson = json_encode($data_values); //if you want json
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to remove the index from the JSON, here is the way:

```
$json = '{
    "2": "12:40 to 13:0",
    "3": "13:0 to 13:20",
    "4": "13:20 to 13:40",
    "5": "13:40 to 14:0",
    "6": "14:0 to 14:20",
    "7": "14:20 to 14:40",
    "8": "14:40 to 15:0",
    "9": "15:0 to 15:20",
    "10": "15:20 to 15:40",
    "11": "15:40 to 16:0",
    "12": "16:0 to 16:20",
    "13": "16:20 to 16:40",
    "14": "16:40 to 17:0",
    "15": "17:0 to 17:20",
    "16": "17:20 to 17:40",
    "17": "17:40 to 18:0"
    }';
 $json = json_encode(array_values(json_decode($json,true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
$json = '{
    "2": "12:40 to 13:0",
    "3": "13:0 to 13:20",
    "4": "13:20 to 13:40",
    "5": "13:40 to 14:0",
    "6": "14:0 to 14:20",
    "7": "14:20 to 14:40",
    "8": "14:40 to 15:0",
    "9": "15:0 to 15:20",
    "10": "15:20 to 15:40",
    "11": "15:40 to 16:0",
    "12": "16:0 to 16:20",
    "13": "16:20 to 16:40",
    "14": "16:40 to 17:0",
    "15": "17:0 to 17:20",
    "16": "17:20 to 17:40",
    "17": "17:40 to 18:0"

}';

echo json_encode(array_values(json_decode($json, true)));
?>
```

`{"12:40 to 13:0","13:0 to 13:20",.....}` this is not valid json format when key does not in JOSN.

correct format is `["12:40 to 13:0","13:0 to 13:20","13:20 to 13:40".....]`